# combining css files into one breaks the site layout

Tags: html, css, assetic

I have a site that I am working on and I've been running on dev mode, where it doesn't combine all the css files that I have into a single script. Everything worked totally fine. When running on prod, all of my css files is combined into a single file. This is using assetic to do so, however what happened is that everything breaks like crazy. Can anyone tell me why this is the case? Is assetic not combining the assets in the right order?

Just for reference, here's the site that runs on [dev](http://dev.shopious.com/marketplace) and here's the site that runs on [prod](http://seller.shopious.com/marketplace)

Comment: You aren't loading all your links:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://seller.shopious.com/images/store_logos//dc976e6beb8945948fa4b357a1794ec81ea3c5ea.jpeg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://seller.shopious.com/images/store_logos//60f861e6913d6c0cb8d92a4cb0c8353c5fb68bea.jpeg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://seller.shopious.com/images/store_logos//01c4c6919289999c8d0a8d174eac52c65930e403.jpeg

Comment: That has nothing to do with the CSS layout I assume.

Comment: This mean that all your css link aren on the prod website. check inside your header

Comment: That means an image inside the <img src=> tag isn't found, which i am fully aware of. it has nothing to do with the css.

Comment: Yep, those images shouldn't be affecting the CSS. It looks like they aren't loading because of the double slash in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is that there is an error in the combined CSS file. Some errors affect parsing the rest of the stylesheet, so it just stops. It is why you aren't encountering it as bad in the individual files as it's not the entire styling of the page stopping however I do think there will be one or two declarations that are not loading in those individual files.

Have a look [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.shopious.com%2Fmarketplace&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) at your Dev site's CSS validation. While a bunch of the errors are just straight from bootstrap and won't cause the parsing to stop altogether, there are some other errors that could affect the rest of the parsing of the sheet.

Things like this:

```
#order-history .
#order-history .data-block img {
```

That is line 73 of http://dev.shopious.com/css/3a76827_part_6_order-history_11.css

Just check through the validation results carefully and see what errors you find.

Comment: @Tumerj that is a really nice catch.

Comment: It was fairly lucky I spotted that amongst the errors. Again though, a lot of them aren't so serious to cause you issues however it does show a lot of the little hacks for IE or the different browser specific features that aren't considered valid.